# SQL Server stored procedure Python passed file path

Tags: python, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to pass a file directory to a Python script in order to process the contents. Here is the `EXEC` statement and below my code is the error. It is supposed open the file and do some processing.

EXEC ScrapeData 'F:\FinancialResearch\SEC\myEdgar\sec-edgar-filings\WIRE\10-Q\0001753926-20-000110\full-submission.txt'

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS ScrapeData;
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ScrapeData] 
    (@filepath varchar(300))
AS
BEGIN
    EXEC sp_execute_external_script
            @language = N'Python',
            @script = N'
import html2text
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pyodbc
import re
import requests
import pandas as pd

with open(@filepath) as f:
        contents = f.read()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(contents, ''lxml'')
.....
```

Error:

> Msg 39004, Level 16, State 20, Line 0
> A 'Python' script error occurred during execution of 'sp_execute_external_script' with HRESULT 0x80004004.
>
> Msg 39019, Level 16, State 2, Line 0
> An external script error occurred:
>
> Error in execution.  Check the output for more information.
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "", line 3, in 
> File "E:\ProgramData\REAPER\Temp-PY\Appcontainer1\DE944528-CBDA-4AFD-B50F-32AD2CFD35B7\sqlindb_0.py", line 45
> with open(@filepath) as f:
> ^
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>
> SqlSatelliteCall error: Error in execution. Check the output for more information.
>
> STDOUT message(s) from external script:

SqlSatelliteCall function failed. Please see the console output for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

...for a file c:\temp\test.txt..

```
declare @myfile varchar(100) = 'c:\temp\test.txt';

EXEC sp_execute_external_script @language = N'Python', @script = N'
print(filename)
print(xyz)
print(paramZ)
num_lines = sum(1 for line in open(filename))
print("------")
print(num_lines)
',
@params= N'@filename varchar(100), @paramZ int, @xyz varchar(10)', @filename = @myfile, @xyz='abcd', @paramZ = 100;
```

Comment: .. @DavidOlsen .. 