# Using variables/dynamic SQL in SQL Server machine learning Python

Tags: python, sql, sql-server

I'm trying to automate the import of Excel fields using  combination or SQL and Python.

I've writing the file detection part in SQL where I can extract the filenames and store them into a variable in SQL but when I try to use the variables in the Python script it throws an error.

Is there a way around this or will the whole thing have to be in Python?

The desired result hopefully would id be able to wrap a loop around the whole thing and the multiple files would be parsed through the python script and loaded into a SQL table

Code is below:

```
DECLARE @PythonScript NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'
import pandas as pd
df = pd.ExcelFile('+@filepath+')
print(df.sheet_names)

'
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69138119/sql-server-stored-procedure-python-passed-file-path/69138530#69138530

Comment: Pass them as parameters to `sp_execute_external_script` for example `exec sp_execute_external_script ....... @params = N'@filepath nvarchar(255)', @filepath = @filepath;`